# Подскажите как написать собственный метод Slice

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте подскажите как написать собственный метод который бы работал как slice для строк.

Comment: Разрешите поинтересоваться зачем?

Comment: для того что бы понять как именно он работает со строками.

Comment: но ведь у строк есть метод `slice()` ...

Comment: я знаю. Мне нужно понять как именно он работает..

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как именно работает `slice()`, но предположу, что как-то приблизительно так:

```js
console.log(stringSlice('Какая-то строка', 9));
console.log(stringSlice('Какая-то строка', 3, 11));

function stringSlice( string, begin, end ) {
  let newString = '';

  end = end || string.length - 1;

  for(let i = begin; i <= end; i++) {
    newString += string[i];
  }
  
  return newString;
}
```

---

**UPD:**
Вот [ТУТ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Streamlining_cross-browser_behavior) есть собственно описание того как это работает на примере с "кросс-браузерной прокладкой" для массива.

> ```
> /**
>  * Прокладка для "исправления" отсутствия поддержки в IE < 9 применения slice
>  * к хост-объектам вроде NamedNodeMap, NodeList и HTMLCollection
>  * (технически, поскольку хост-объекты зависят от реализации,
>  * по крайней мере, до ES2015, IE не обязан так работать).
>  * Также работает для строк, исправляет поведение IE < 9, позволяя явно указывать undefined
>  * вторым аргументом (как в Firefox), и предотвращает ошибки, возникающие при
>  * вызове на других объектах DOM.
>  */
> (function () {
>   'use strict';
>   var _slice = Array.prototype.slice;
>
>   try {
>     // Не может использоваться с элементами DOM в IE < 9
>     _slice.call(document.documentElement);
>   } catch (e) { // В IE < 9 кидается исключение
>     // Функция будет работать для истинных массивов, массивоподобных объектов,
>     // NamedNodeMap (атрибуты, сущности, примечания),
>     // NodeList (например, getElementsByTagName), HTMLCollection (например, childNodes)
>     // и не будет падать на других объектах DOM (как это происходит на элементах DOM в IE < 9)
>     Array.prototype.slice = function(begin, end) {
>       // IE < 9 будет недоволен аргументом end, равным undefined
>       end = (typeof end !== 'undefined') ? end : this.length;
>
>       // Для родных объектов Array мы используем родную функцию slice
>       if (Object.prototype.toString.call(this) === '[object Array]') {
>         return _slice.call(this, begin, end); 
>       }
>
>       // Массивоподобные объекты мы обрабатываем самостоятельно
>       var i, cloned = [],
>           size, len = this.length;
>
>       // Обрабатываем отрицательное значение begin
>       var start = begin || 0;
>       start = (start >= 0) ? start: len + start;
>
>       // Обрабатываем отрицательное значение end
>       var upTo = (end) ? end : len;
>       if (end < 0) {
>         upTo = len + end;
>       }
>
>       // Фактически ожидаемый размер среза
>       size = upTo - start;
>
>       if (size > 0) {
>         cloned = new Array(size);
>         if (this.charAt) {
>           for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
>             cloned[i] = this.charAt(start + i);
>           }
>         } else {
>           for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
>             cloned[i] = this[start + i];
>           }
>         }
>       }
>
>       return cloned;
>     };
>   }
> }());
> ```

Comment: а если задавать минусовые значения в begin или end?

Comment: @Анна, я вам привел лишь поверхностную логику, без проверок типов, значений и так далее. Более подробно можно глянуть по аналогии с тем, как это работает для массивов, дал ссылку и зацитировал код для потомков.